# How to securely checkout SVN from shell script?

Tags: svn, solaris

I want to have a script on my Solaris machine that can checkout SVN code. However, the repository will require a username and password. How can I do this securely so I do not have to hardcode the password and other people cannot see the password if looking at the script?

I would log in as myself, then sudo to an account that would be by multiple people.

Comment: Depends on the transport used to check out? http. ssh. etc.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this securely

On every and each platform SVN stores some (and auth-related too) data into user-specific directory. AFAICR, it must be `~/.subversion` (`auth` subdir for stored credentials)

If you can at least one perform any authorized operation under user, which will be used later for running script (and enter username|password by hand), stored credentials will be cached and used without any additional user-side intervention